# gatling-maven-plugin StackOverflowError

Tags: maven, gatling

When I build my simle Scenario I get this. How can I give the gateling-maven-plugin more memory?

```
[INFO] --- gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.1:execute (default-cli) @ portal-performance ---
15:37:40.834 [main][WARN ][ZincCompiler.scala:142] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.
15:37:49.115 [main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:156] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.make(Contexts.scala:467)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.makeSilent(Contexts.scala:515)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:675)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer you are looking for.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/VV7S50ntHq8

Comment: Yes, the record tool recorded too long chains. You can just cut the chains in smaller chains, and then it works :)